# Best Suitable NoSql Database for storing XML files

Tags: xml, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a use case where i need to store huge number of xml files approximately 10 TB.The size of the each xml files varies from  10kb to 3 mb .
I have to make primary key and based on that i have to retrieve full xml files.

There can be scenario where we might have to fetch some tags from different xml files also .
I was planing to use DynamoDB but then it does not directly support xml files and also size of the value in the DynamoDB should not exceed 400kb that makes it not fit for our use case .

please suggest us some other databases that can be suitable for our requirement .

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution close to what you want is dynamodb db in combination with s3.
You will not store any xml files in dynamodb since it is goind to cost you a lot, plus there is a kb limit in each dynamodb entry.
Instead you will store in s3 the xml file and you will use dynamo to store any information that shall be queried (including metadata) that will fetch your the name of the s3 file.

Then you will use s3 to retrieve the file.

Keep in mind that there is no need to do this with dynamodb if you already use another database.